# Is it possible to select data with a function call using EF Code First and an Oracle Database?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF Code First on an Oracle Database. Given a table like this

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

is it possible to construct a where clause that contains a call to a function?

e.g

```
MyDatabase database = new MyDatabase();

var results = database.Entity.Where(c => c.Id < 1000 
                            && "Schema.Package.Function(" + c.Id + "));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696332%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method

```
var results = database.Entity
  .SqlQuery("select c.* from Entity c where c.Id < 1000 and Schema.Package.Function(c.Id)");
```